# Magento - Cant find the insert action in downloadable products

Tags: php, database, magento

Hi was looking for the action that makes the insert when i click on downloadable product

[image]

The insert its made in table downloadable_link; how magento does the insert process to add a field in the current table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i founded in ww\magento\app\code\local\Mage\Downloadable\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Downloadable\Links.php